# I am having problems with the font size of the navigation bar menu's

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am building a website. The navigation bar has 5 menu's. When I click the menu and open it, the size of the font of the letters of the menu like "Home,Gallery,Contact etc" changes. How can i fix it?

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsbin or jsfiddle type of site so we can see what you got?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots to demonstrate the problem you are describing?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm...

```
<font style="font-size: --px">lalala</font> - No?
```

If your code doesn't work, you always can take a screen of your buttons and place it as background-image:

```
<style> .LALA {background-image: url('example.png'); repeat: no-repeat; width: --px;} </style>

<button class="LALA"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the menu is active, put the `.active` class and through this class set the styles for the open menu. Most likely you have some other styles applied